# Facebook oauth server-side / no code exchange when ref=m_notif

Tags: facebook, mobile, server-side, facebook-oauth

I have a facebook app in a canvas that is working very fine.
I enabled referral authentification.
I recently enabled my mobile web app link, so now I can access my app from facebook app or from 
http://m.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP

I coded the necessary server-side handling of the ?code= parameters to generate an access_token so it works fine. (I request access_token using a redirect_uri that is my current url up to "&code=")

My problem is when I try to open my mobile web app from an app request (on my mobile), The access_token request fails (surely because of the redirect_uri parameter).

After a lot of investigation I found out that the only problem was the **ref=m_notif** paramater.

Basically if I try to access my app with `m.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP/*almost any string or parameter I want*` it works
BUT
If I try to access my app with `m.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP/?ref=m_notif`  it FAILS. any other `ref=*string*` is fine.

Do you know what I should do here ?

Thanks a lot